# C# How to unite two data types into a list

Tags: c#, list, hierarchy

I have a simple RegistrationCountByMonth table

```
public int RegistrationCountByMonthId { get; set; }
public short? Year { get; set; }
public byte? Month { get; set; }
public int? NumberOfUsers { get; set; }
public virtual Month MonthNavigation { get; set; }
```

And a simple CleanByMonth type. Which I should return

```
public short? Year { get; set; }
public byte? Month { get; set; }
public int? NumberOfUsers { get; set; }
```

Why I can't do something like:

```
List<CleanByMonth> cleanMonths = crudeInfoByMonth.Value.Select(x => new { x.Year , x.Month, x.NumberOfUsers}).ToList();
```

crudeInfoByMonth is a RegistrationCountByMonth type.

And I got this error...

```
Cannot convert source type '
System.Collections.Generic.List<{
System.Nullable<short> Year, 
System.Nullable<byte> Month, 
System.Nullable<int> NumberOfUsers}>' 
to target type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Server.ViewModel.CleanByMonth>'
```

Comment: You need to do something like: `List<CleanByMonth> cleanMonths = crudeInfoByMonth.Value.Select(x => new CleanByMonth { x.Year , x.Month, x.NumberOfUsers}).ToList();` (give or take). You can't just select a new anonymous object, you have to create new `CkeanByMonth` instances

Comment: @Flydog57 thanks for your help. 
But it still doesn't work. 
I made something like this:
`List<CleanByMonth> cleanMonths = crudeInfoByMonth.Value
                            .Select(x => new CleanByMonth {x.Year , x.Month, x.NumberOfUsers}).ToList();`
And on every `x.field` it says Cannot resolve symbol 'Add'

Answer (score 0):

An anonymous type is also a type just like your `CleanByMonth`, so you cannot just convert it. Declare the variable as `var` so it can be recognized as anonymous.

```
var cleanMonths = crudeInfoByMonth.Value.Select(x => new { x.Year , x.Month, x.NumberOfUsers}).ToList();
```

But if you still want it as a list of `CleanByMonth`, you can replace the anonymous in between your line with the actual type clean by month like this.

```
List<CleanByMonth> cleanMonths = crudeInfoByMonth.Value.
    Select(x => new CleanByMonth { x.Year , x.Month, x.NumberOfUsers}).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But it still doesn't work. I made something like this: List<CleanByMonth> cleanMonths = crudeInfoByMonth.Value                             .Select(x => new CleanByMonth {x.Year , x.Month, x.NumberOfUsers}).ToList(); And on every x.field it says Cannot resolve symbol 'Add'

Comment: It means something else is wrong with your code. update the question with the details of `crudeInfoByMonth`